# Vue-Cli, how to disable camel case warnings

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I am trying to disable the Eslint camelcase rule by setting it to either "off" or 0 in my package.json file. Any idea why it isn't working?

```
  "eslintConfig": {
"root": true,
"env": {
  "node": true
},
"extends": [
  "plugin:vue/essential",
  "eslint:recommended",
  "@vue/typescript/recommended"
],
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 2020
},
"rules": {
  "camelcase": "off"
},
"overrides": [
  {
    "files": [
      "**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)",
      "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)"
    ],
    "env": {
      "mocha": true
    }
  }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the settings as per your requirement:

```
"rules": {
  "properties": "never",
  "ignoreDestructuring": true,
  "ignoreImports": false
},
```

Here is the default setting and description:

1. "properties": "always" (default) enforces camelcase style for property names
2. "ignoreDestructuring": false (default) enforces camelcase style for destructured identifiers
3. "ignoreImports": false (default) enforces camelcase style for ES2015 imports

More info here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/camelcase

Comment: Should I be putting these settings in the "rules" section? When I do I get a compile error

Comment: @jhowell96, I have updated my answer, let me know if that was helpful.

Comment: @jhowell96, if this solved your problem then do you mind to mark this as Selected Answer & up vote it :)